# How to approach getting permission to remote work outside the US as a programmer for a US based company/staffing company?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, remote-work, onboarding

I am a US citizen currently based in New York and just got a job as an android developer (W2, 1 year contract, hourly rate) for a major US company through a staffing company that is also based in the USA.

**As part of the on-boarding paperwork I signed (through the staffing company) I had to agree to conduct my work inside the USA *unless given permission to work outside the USA*.**

At some point in my programming career I would like to work in Mexico/Central America for 2-3 weeks here and there throughout the year just to break things up of working in the dreary city all the time.

However since I am just starting with this company and being a junior developer I didn't want to make a big deal about it or even try to negotiate it in the deal so that I could get hired.

Does anyone have experience/advice on how to approach getting permission to *temporarily* work outside the USA (not live) as a programmer from their staffing company / end client?

What would be the best way to ask and sell my case??

Comment: `1.` So you have specific plans during the course of this particular one year contract to work outside of the USA? `2`. Wouldn't the most straightforward way of getting an answer be to ask the staffing company?

Comment: In what industry is the client in? Do they deal with medical data, financial data, etc. Anyway, before you ask the staffing agency, get to know the client first. You need to find out if this restriction is coming from the client, or if it's boiler plate inserted by the staffing agency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The clue here is in the wording of the agreement that you signed:

> unless given permission to work outside the USA

Simply put, ask your manager how this permission process works and what requirements employees need to meet in order to gain that permission.

You don't know at this point how strict that clause is or whether many people work abroad.  It could be a very tight confidentiality reason, or it might just be there for finance/tax purposes.

There's really no harm at all in asking.

Comment: It is quite possible that there is no process and nobody ever gets permission. But asking your manager won’t hurt. Just say “I was thinking it would be useful for me to work from Mexico for two or three weeks. Do you think that’s possible?”